Improving efficiency of uj in kdb for a large table
I have a not so massive table. About 500k records.
But it is a nested JSON.
I have to load it, parse it and flatten the dict (each row is a dict and can have different depths)
This takes quite some time, but manageable (maybe around 4-5 minutes)
However, at some point I need to take all these rows and uj them
 (uj/) enlist each row // this takes quite a bit

I only have 2 cores to use in dev and maybe 4 in prod/dr
Using 2 cores I saved some time, but not something that motivated me to update our infrastructure.
Is there anything I am doing wrong ?
Anything I am missing ?
I know you could use some data, but creating a synthetic table won't be much help.
Should I maybe consider starting 10 new secondary procs and split the ~500k in 50k sets and pass them to these processes to be processed ?
This table has 492000 records and 103 columns.

You can try to look at the full set for all known columns names in advance:
q)columns:distinct raze key each row
q)protoDict:columns!count[columns]#(::)
q)tab:protoDict,/:rows

This would leave you with generic null values (::) in the table then you'd want to filter out afterwards. Ideally you'd create the protoDict and use the known correct nulls per column but it seems you suggest you cannot know this.
.i.e
q)tab:([] a:(1.0;::;2.0);b:("";::;"test");c:(1b;::;0b))
q)tab
a  b      c
------------
1f ""     1b
:: ::     ::
2f "test" 0b

Then:
q)fillNulls:0N -9 -1 10h!((::);0Nf;0b;"")
q)nulls:{fillNulls type first x where not (::)~/:x}each flip tab;
q){i:where (::)~/:tab x;tab[x]:@[tab x;i;:;i#enlist nulls x]}each columns:cols tab;

Becomes:
q)tab
a b      c
----------
1 ""     1
  ""     0
2 "test" 0

Note:

Above approach only makes sense it the column contents are not of mixed type.
It is still inefficient - you always want to try and know the full universe of column names and their types in advance if you want fast processing of JSON dictionaries.

Related: https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-parsing-json-files/

A few questions: How exactly are you parsing the Json file? Are you using the inbuild jason parser https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotj/ ? Are the dictionaries conform? i.e do they have the same keys? If so, you don't have to enlist them, a list of conform dictionaries is basically a table. You can read more about dictionaries and tables here: https://www.defconq.tech/docs/concepts/dictionariesTables

the problem is the (uj/). As I have mentioned all the other operations work fine.

I get to a point where I have a list of dictionaries with different keys. The uj is meant to create a table with all rows and all columns even if they're empty
